# Cumulative histogram for 2D data in Python

Tags: python, matplotlib

My data consists of a 2-D array of masses and distances. I want to produce a plot where the x-axis is distance and the y axis is the number of data elements with distance <= x (i.e. a cumulative histogram plot). What is the most efficient way to do this with Python?

PS: the masses are irrelevant since I already have filtered by mass, so all I am trying to produce is a plot using the distance data.

Example plot below:

[image: Example]

Comment: please share sample data.

Comment: The data can be anything, for example data = np.arange(0,5,0.1)

Comment: My real data looks something like this:

[2.0796793,   0.81360986,  3.84907469  ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I figured I can do given a 1D array of data:

```
plt.figure()
counts = np.ones(len(data))
plt.step(np.sort(data), counts.cumsum())
plt.show()
```

This apparently works with duplicate elements also, as the ys will be added for each x.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can combine [numpy.cumsum()](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.cumsum.html) and [plt.step()](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.step.html):

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

N = 15
distances = np.random.uniform(1, 4, 15).cumsum()
counts = np.random.uniform(0.5, 3, 15)
plt.step(distances, counts.cumsum())
plt.show()
```

[image: example plot]

Alternatively, `plt.bar` can be used to draw a histogram, with the widths defined by the difference between successive distances. Optionally, an extra distance needs to be appended to give the last bar a width.

```py
plt.bar(distances, counts.cumsum(), width=np.diff(distances, append=distances[-1]+1), align='edge')
plt.autoscale(enable=True, axis='x', tight=True)  # make x-axis tight
```

[image: bar plot]
Instead of appending a value, e.g. a zero could be prepended, depending on the exact interpretation of the data.

```py
plt.bar(distances, counts.cumsum(), width=-np.diff(distances, prepend=0), align='edge')
```

Comment: Can you please clarify "distances" and "counts"? If distances is my list of mass data, what is counts?

Comment: You wrote `I want to produce a plot where the x-axis is distance and the y axis is the number of data elements with distance <= x`. Well, I interpreted the 'distances' as an x-axis of ever increasing numbers. And 'counts' as 'the number of data elements'. Feel free to edit and clarify the text of your question if you intend something else. Maybe you can add some dummy data and some code to at least draw a plot of that data (without cumulating)?